# How to query NVIDIA GPU parameters for a certain PID?

Tags: process, profiling, gpu, nvidia

I know with `nvidia-smi` an overview is generated like:

```
+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| NVIDIA-SMI 375.66                 Driver Version: 375.66                    |
|-------------------------------+----------------------+----------------------+
| GPU  Name        Persistence-M| Bus-Id        Disp.A | Volatile Uncorr. ECC |
| Fan  Temp  Perf  Pwr:Usage/Cap|         Memory-Usage | GPU-Util  Compute M. |
|===============================+======================+======================|
|   0  Quadro P4000        Off  | 0000:01:00.0     Off |                  N/A |
| N/A   43C    P0    26W /  N/A |    227MiB /  8114MiB |      0%      Default |
+-------------------------------+----------------------+----------------------+

+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| Processes:                                                       GPU Memory |
|  GPU       PID  Type  Process name                               Usage      |
|=============================================================================|
|    0      1724    G   /usr/bin/X                                     219MiB |
|    0      8074    G   qtcreator                                        6MiB |
+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------+
```

However, for the parameters I'd like to break it down for each process (e.g. GPU usage, used memory). I can't find a respective query, but then again I can't imagine that such a basic function is not implemented. Hence

Is there an easy way to display the GPU parameters for each process?

Answer (score 1):

I don't think it gets any closer to `nvidia-smi pmon`:

```
# gpu     pid  type    sm   mem   enc   dec    fb   command
# Idx       #   C/G     %     %     %     %    MB   name
    0    1750     G     1     0     0     0   179   X              
    0    3734     G     0     0     0     0     7   qtcreator
```